# Show only a portion of an image with java

Tags: java, image, graphics, sprite

If I have a large image that is made up of 25 x 25 smaller images in a grid. How can I use java to only show a portion of that larger grid (such as drawing a portion that starts at 125,25 and ends showing at 150,50)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd break up the image into smaller images, put the smaller image cells into their own ImageIcons and then display whichever Icons I desired in JLabels, perhaps several of them. `BufferedImage#getSubimage(...)` can help you break the big image into smaller ones.

(decided to make it an answer)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need a physical copy of the sub image and only need to display it then you could add the image to a JLabel which you add to a JScrollPane without any scrollbars. Set the preferredSize() of the scrollpane equal to the dimension of your sub images (25x25). Then you can use

```
scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(...);
```

to position the viewport to disply any sub image.